# How to format database datetime in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datetime value gotten from an SQLServer database table:

```
2016-08-16T17:00:00Z
```

Using javascript, I want to format the date as follow:

```
16/08/2016 17:00:00
```

I have used the code below:

```
$scope.FormatDate = function (value) {
        if (value !== null && typeof (value) !== 'undefined') {
            var date = new Date(value);
            var returnStr = date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getFullYear();
            return returnStr;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

The result from the sample resource is:

```
17/71/2016
```

I want your help to get the output result as: "16/08/2016 17:00:00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is format it then you don't need to create an actual date object, you can do a simple string replace using a regex to grab the individual parts, as per this simple demo:

```js
var value = "2016-08-16T17:00:00Z";
console.log(value.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T([^Z]+)Z/,"$3/$2/$1 $4"));
```

In the context of your function:

```
$scope.FormatDate = function (value) {
  if (value !== null && typeof (value) !== 'undefined') {
    return value.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T([^Z]+)Z/,"$3/$2/$1 $4");
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the result I want, but it can solve my current issue. Anyway, I have marked it as my solution.

Comment: *"This is not exactly the result I want"* - The result you *explictly asked for* was `16/08/2016 17:00:00`, which is exactly what my code produces.

Comment: I just mean the way you fix it. :D

Comment: By the way, the reason the month was coming out as `71` in your code is that `..."/" + date.getMonth() + 1...` does a string concatenation - you need to add 1 to the month before concatenating, which is as simple as adding parentheses: `..."/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + ...`. You're getting the day as 17 because of a timezone issue, which in my opinion isn't worth worrying about when a one-line string replace gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```js
var parsed = Date.parse("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z"),
    date = new Date(parsed),
    day = date.getUTCDate(),
    month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
    year = date.getUTCFullYear(),
    hour = date.getUTCHours(),
    minute = date.getUTCMinutes(),
    second = date.getUTCSeconds(),
    dateStr = "";

day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
minute = minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : minute;
second = second < 10 ? "0" + second : second;

dateStr = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

console.log(dateStr);
```

**Updated**: The old code may change across countries, because they have different local date/time format, so I have updated to format it explicitly.

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet" the result I get is `"8/17/2016 3:00:00 AM"`.

Comment: You can control the result you want by this: 

var dateStr = date.getDate() + 1 + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function formatDate(date) 
    {
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var seconds = date.getSeconds();


      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds ;
      return  date.getMonth()+1 + "/" +  date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "  " + strTime;

     }
```

Comment: I have tried. It didn't work out. Could you check again on fiddle?  https://jsfiddle.net/2142eotp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to format the date as you desire with implementing some logic.

http://momentjs.com/

Just work with the function parameter **value** and use moment.

Example:

```
const date = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").date();
const month = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").month();
const hour = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").hour();
const year = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").year();
const minute = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").minute();
const sec = moment("2016-08-16T17:00:00Z").second();
// implementing some logic
console.log('' + date + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + sec);
```

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/6m4m7mp3/